# How to delete a node from circular singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having some issues in removing a single node/value from a circular single linked list in a recursive manner (if it's possible of course). My code deletes only from the middle but not from the first or last place.

I could not figure out how to make the connection after deleting one of them in a recursive way. I mean, if I'm deleting the first element then I need to connect the last node to the next node.

Here is my code:

```
Node *ListDelete(Node *list, Node *tail, int val, Node **deleted) {
    if (!list || (list == tail && list->value != val)) {
        *deleted = NULL;
        return list;
    }

    if (list->value == val) {
        *deleted = list;
        return list->next;
    }

    list->next = ListDelete(list->next, tail, val, deleted);
    return list;
}
```

Arguments and return:

```
        case MENU_DELETE:
            val = GetValue("Enter value");
            if (list) tail = FindTail(list);
            list = ListDelete(list, tail, val, &node);
            ListPrintNode(node, "Deleted");
            free(node);
```

Find tail function:

```
Node* FindTail(Node* list)
{
    Node* temp = list;
    while(temp->next != list)
        temp = temp->next;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but I don't see any attempt here at reconnecting the previous and next element. You'll need to pass in the previous node into the recursive function, otherwise there's no way to link it to the element after the deleted node. Please show a minimal example that it's failing on and what the desired result should be. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably show specifically what happens if you try to delete the first or last element of, say, a 2-element list. You haven't posted complete code, so I can't reproduce anything, and I wouldn't know what behaviour I was trying to reproduce anyway.

Comment: Its deleting only if the node is at the middle or at the end, when i try to delete to first one its only passing the node to the end.. and if there is a single or 2- element the program collapse.

Comment: What are the arguments and the return value supposed to be? especially what is `tail`? *My code deletes only from the middle but not from the first or last place.* is this a requirement? A circular list does not really have a tail.

Comment: tail its the last node, thats my stop condition, when tail == list i know that i'm at the last node right now. And if you need to remove the first node you need to know who is the last because you need to make that connection.

Comment: This API is perverse. There is no *tail* node for an empty list or one reduced to a single node. Is the API a requirement?

Comment: thats the reason i'm checking if (list) because if its empty it wo'nt look for any tail..

Comment: Well if `list` is `NULL`, `FindTail(list)` should return `NULL` as well. What if `list` has a single element, ie: if `list->next == list`, what does `FindTail(list)` return in this case?

Comment: It will return the node as a tail too, it will skip the while loop and return same node as tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for `ListDelete` is has a `tail` argument that is not required.

Here is an implementation without such an argument. It returns a pointer to the circular list from which the first node with `value == val` starting at `list->next` and stores the pointer to this node into `*deleted`:

```c
Node *ListDelete(Node *list, int val, Node **deleted) {
    // special case empty and singleton lists
    if (!list || (list == list->next && list->value != val)) {
        *deleted = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    if (list == list->next) {
        *deleted = list;
        return NULL;
    }
    for (Node *node = list;; node = node->next) {
        if (node->next->value == val) {
            *deleted = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            if (list == *deleted)
                list = node->next;
            return list;
        } else
        if (node->next == list)
            *deleted = NULL;
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

With your API, here is a corrected version of your code:

```c
Node *ListDelete(Node *list, Node *tail, int val, Node **deleted) {
    if (!list || (list == list->next && list->value != val)) {
        *deleted = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    if (list == list->next) {
        *deleted = list;
        return NULL;
    ]
    if (list->next->value == val) {
        *deleted = list->next;
        list->next = list->next->next;
        return list;
    }
    if (list == tail) {
        *deleted = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    ListDelete(list->next, tail, val, deleted);
    if (list == *deleted)
        list = list->next;
    return list;
}
```

The downside of this recursive implementation is the depth of recursion is the length of the list. This recursion is not tail recursion, so a sufficiently long list will cause a **stack overflow**.

To avoid this, you can convert the function to a non recursive one:

```c
Node *ListDelete(Node *list, Node *tail, int val, Node **deleted) {
    // special case empty and singleton lists
    if (!list || (list == list->next && list->value != val)) {
        *deleted = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    if (list == list->next) {
        *deleted = list;
        return NULL;
    }
    for (Node *node = list;; node = node->next) {
        if (node->next->value == val) {
            *deleted = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            if (list == *deleted)
                list = node->next;
            return list;
        } else
        if (node == tail) { // equivalent to if (node->next == list)
            *deleted = NULL;
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I tried to split it to 2 diffrent functions, one only for head removing and the second for other cases, its worked but yours better !

Comment: @ValeriF21: I updated the answer: the recursive version should not return list if this node is the deleted one. I also simplified the non-recursive version.